# Only variables can be passed by reference in

Tags: php

Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

В этой строчке:

```
foreach ($arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"]["72"] as $key=>$moreimg)
{
    CWaterMark::PostWaterMark($moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]);
}
```

Массив имеет вид

```
[78] => Array
                (
                    [n0] => Array
                        (
                            [VALUE] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => c8b79ce78f_154881.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => /var/www/4.ru/data/mod-tmp/php0B6qCw
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 163406
                                )

                            [DESCRIPTION] => 
                        )

                    [n1] => Array
                        (
                            [VALUE] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => erheben2.jpg
                                    [type] => image/jpeg
                                    [tmp_name] => /var/www/4.ru/data/mod-tmp/phpkZmLY3
                                    [error] => 0
                                    [size] => 225747
                                )

                            [DESCRIPTION] => 
                        )
```

Comment: рад за вас. А в чем вопрос? 
1) Как выглядит массив?
2) существует ли на каждом шаге $moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]?
3) чему она равна?

Comment: Согласен. Лучше было выложить хотя бы 2 ветки массива, чтобы мы поняли, что человеку надо, иначе и не понять, что у него внутри творится и где ошибка. И может не `$moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]`, а `$$moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]` если уж юзается величина переменной.

Comment: обновил

Comment: $arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"]["**72**"], а массив - для 78. Это не фатально?

Comment: Ошибка исчезла. Функция не срабатывает.

Comment: `$moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]` выдает нормально результат. Замените свое `CWaterMark::PostWaterMark($moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]);` Например, на  `echo "{$moreimg["VALUE"]["tmp_name"]}";`
 специально массив создал по вашим веткам и проверил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдено в интернетах:

```
CWaterMark::PostWaterMark(&$arFields["PROPERTY_VALUES"]["72"][$key]['VALUE']['tmp_name']);
```

Обратите внимание на **&**

Comment: Ровным счетом ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Обновил, попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо :)
Я и правда лопухнулся с номером свойства)) как подсказал ling)